# SQL Server Corruption & Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, corruption

I have a situation where storage was ripped out from under SQL Server.  After running BBCC CheckDB I have received an "Extent (1:269886) in database ID 34 is allocated by more than one allocation object" message.

The research I have done basically tells me recover from backup.  However, this table is a subscriber in transactional replication.  Replication is set up such that I have added individual articles in the past in order to initialize in stages.  Am I correct that I can do the following:

1. Remove the article from replication
2. Add the article back
3. Let the agent job take a new snapshot
4. Let that snapshot apply

Do I need to truncate or drop the damaged table first?

SQL  Server 2008R2 on Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your steps are correct and you do not need to truncate or drop as you will be generating new snapshot for that one article.

Few things to check:

- When you drop article, also drop subscription.
- Make sure `immediate_sync` property of your publication is set to
  false so you do not end up with a full snapshot (of all articles).

These two threads has details about where things might go wrong.

- [Add article to transactional publication without generating new snapshot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/add-article-to-transactional-publication-without-generating-new-snapshot)
- http://ansqldba.blogspot.com/2012/02/adding-new-article-to-existing.html

Comment: just a quote,in sql server 2016,you can drop article with out reinitializing replication