# Data missing on Subscriber Database in SQL server transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have Transactional replication set up between a server 'A' and server 'B', where the Data from 'A' is getting replicated on the server B as database "B".

There is an issue reporting that one row in the subscriber database 'B' is missing. I re-tried the replication several times, still that one row is missing. Other than that, everything looks fine.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "*re-tried the replication*"?...have you tried generating a new snapshot for the distributor to work off of?

Comment: @Kay, can you give an example of the table? I suppose this is not a large table, right; it's something with 10-20 rows, maybe?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani after further investigation, i found the subscriber was paused syncing at some time in the past (say April 01), and then it re-started to sync (say June 01), and all data between those two times were not loaded into the subscriber.

Comment: @Kay, so is the problem solved now?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, not yet, would there be a way to sync the data during the period when the subscriber was paused?

Answer (score 1):

The solution will depend on two things.

1. Size of the table, including the number of records
2. Can you afford downtime to resync the full table

If it is a smaller table (generally speaking), you can use a data comparison tool (visual studio, Redgate SQL data compare or any other third-party tools) and sync the tables from source to target. If you have constraints, it might not work.

If you can afford downtime, you can drop this table (article) and add it back without a full snapshot of other articles in the same publication. See details [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/add-article-to-transactional-publication-without-generating-new-snapshot).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know I could do that without doing the full snapshot. Thank you